# Does G-d have expiration on His tolerance?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, middos-character-traits

> וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל־מֹשֶׁה עַד־אָנָה יְנַאֲצֻנִי הָעָם הַזֶּה
>   וְעַד־אָנָה לֹא־יַאֲמִינוּ בִי בְּכֹל הָאֹתוֹת אֲשֶׁר עָשִׂיתִי בְּקִרְבּוֹ׃
>
> And the LORD said to Moses, “How long will this people spurn Me, and how long will they have no faith in Me despite all the signs that I have performed in their midst? ([Num 14,11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.14.11?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

This pattern of G-d complaining about His patience expiring is very common in the Torah. Moreover, it appears that people suffer harder punishment from G-d when sinning for another time. This appears contradicting the idea of "מלך בשר ודם" vs "מלך מה"מ" - G-d being ultimately just, and contradicting our current state of Halacha.

G-d does not have (shouldn't have) tolerance or patience, not mentioning it to expire, IMHO.

Does G-d have an expiration on His tolerance? (and if yes,) Why does Torah picture G-d as such?

Comment: Excellent question! I thought you were going to use the angle that G-d is *Erech Apa'im*, *Maleh Rachamim*, and numerous other similar adages. I think Midrash discusses your question in its explanation of the 13 Middot. If you have a copy of Art Scroll Yom Kippur machzor, view its explanation of the 13 middot. I think it discusses this aspect, there.

Comment: The last two questions seem unrelated to the title. I think you want to know just if G-d's patience is limited. The other two relate to the general question of depicting G-d in human terms, which is something you asked, already, recently, IIRC.

Comment: @DanF Thanks edited, my question raises from the practical application of that trait - He punishes more severely if it happens again, and that contradicts our current Halachah.\

Comment: I know you asked a question regarding what exactly their sin was. Have to explore that, a bit. This verse implies a lack of tolerance for their lack of believing in G-d. Which, would put to question that the Golden Calf seems to be the same problem, right? Except that according to most interpretations, that wasn't a lack of faith in G-d. It's that there, they wanted another leader in place of Moshe and G-d who would lead them to Israel.

Comment: @DanF Please help me rephrase it correctly, I'm saying that unequal punishment proves that "G-d loses His patience". How is that possible?

Comment: Offhand, my editing would be based on my incorrect analysis. Here's what I **think** you're getting at. Among G-d's characteristics is *Erech Apayim* (have to find a good translation of that term, but offhand, I think "tolerance" may be fine.) If that's true, does G-d have a limit, and what conditions would break that limit. For example, regarding the spy mission ... then you can cite your verses as proof of G-d's intolerance / reaching his limit.